# Prolog: Summing elements of two lists representing an integer(restrictions inside not regular sum!!)

Tags: list, prolog

I was solving a problem:
A list is representing an integer say 12345 by L=[12,34,5] each element should be from 0 to 99.The exercise is to write a function (sum) that sums two lists and gives the equivalent list of their sum which is representing the sum of two integers.

```
?-sum([11,11],[11,11],L,0).
L=[22,22].

?-sum([12,81],[11,44],L,0).
L=[24,25].

//digit fxn for making sure that we insert an elemnt of two or single integer 
//and saving the overflow digit in S1.
```

my code that gives me error:

```
digit(X,D,S1):- S is X/100,S1 is integer(S),0 is S1,D is X.

digit(X,D,S1):-D is mod(X/100).

sum([],[],[],0).

sum(H1|T1,H|T,H3|T3,S):-Z is H1+H+S ,digit(Z,H3,S1),sum(T1,T,T3,S1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is for all intents and purposes a base-100 number. The easy way to solve it is to do the arithmetic in the same way in which you would evaluate it long hand: start with the least significant digit, working to the most significant digit, sum each pair of digits, with a carry to the left if the overflows.

We reverse the list so as to let us easily work from right to left. You'll note that the worker predicate `sum_list_mod_100/4` builds is result in the correct order.

```
sum_list_mod_100( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :-       % to compute the sum of a list representing a base-100 integer.
  reverse( Xs , X1 ) ,                    % - reverse the digits of the left hand side (so we're working from least- to most-significant digit)
  reverse( Ys , Y1 ) ,                    % - reverse the digits of the right hand side (so we're working from least- to most-significant digit)
  sum_list_mod_100( X1 , Y1 , 0 , Zs ) .  % - invoke the worker with the carry initialized as zero.
  .

sum_list_mod_100( []     , [] , C , []  ) .         % both lists are empty w/o carry: terminate. 
  C = 0                                             %
  .                                                 %
sum_list_mod_100( []     , [] , C , [C] ) :-        % both lists are empty with a carry: prepend the carry to the result.
  C > 0                                             %
  .                                                 %
sum_list_mod_100( [X|Xs] , [] , C , [Z|Zs]  ) :-    % right-hand side exhausted?
  sum_digits(X,0,C,Z,C1) ,                          % - sum the digits, returning the new digit and the new carry
  sum_list_mod_100( Xs , [] , C1 , Zs )             % - recurse down, passing the new carry
  .                                                 % 
sum_list_mod_100( [] , [Y|Ys] , C , [Z|Zs]  ) :-    % left-hand side exhausted?
  sum_digits(0,Y,C,Z,C1) ,                          % - sum the digits, returning the new digit and the new carry
  sum_list_mod_100( [] , Ys , C1 , Zs )             % - recurse down, passing the new carry
  .                                                 %
sum_list_mod_100( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , C , [Z|Zs] ) :- % not yet exhausted?
  sum_digits(X,Y,C,Z,C1) ,                          % - sum the digits, returning the new digit and the new carry
  sum_list_mod_100( Xs , Ys , C1 , Zs )             % - recurse down passing the new carry
  .                                                 % Easy!

sum_digit(X,Y,C,Z,C1) :-  % to sum two digits (and the carry)
  S is X+Y+C ,            % - sum the LHS, RHS and the carry
  Z is X mod 100 ,        % - compute the digit modulo 100
  C1 is X div 100         % - compute the carry
  .
```

Comment: sum_list_mod_100 is of arity /3 but at the tail it is of arity /4 how is that possible???.

Comment: A common prolog idiom is to have a "public" predicate (in this case, `sum_list_mod_100/3`, that invokes a "private" worker predicate that has an extra argument or two to carry state. Often that worker predicate has the same *functor* (name) as the public predicate, but with a different *arity* (number of arguments). Prolog predicates are unique by functor *and* arity. The two predicates share a common functor, but since they have differing arities, they are in fact different predicates.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

digitFD(X,Zs) :-
   digitFD_aux(X,Zs,[],Zs).

digitFD_aux(X,[_],Zs,[X|Zs]) :-
   X in 0..99.
digitFD_aux(X,[_|Ys],Zs0,Zs) :-
   X #> 99,
   Z #> 0,
   Y in 0..99,
   X #= Y + 100 * Z,
   digitFD_aux(Z,Ys,[Y|Zs0],Zs).
```

Let's test `digitFD/2` a little!

```
?- As = [12,34,56,78], digitFD(N,As).
As = [12,34,56,78], N = 12345678 ;
false.

?- N = 123456789, digitFD(N,As).
N = 123456789, As = [1,23,45,67,89] ;
false.
```

OK! Let's define `sumFD/4`:

```
sumFD(As,Bs,Cs,Zs) :-
   digitFD(A,As), 
   digitFD(B,Bs),
   C #= A+B,
   digitFD(C,Cs),
   append([As,Bs,Cs],Zs).
```

Let's use it!

```
?- sumFD([11,11],[11,11],Xs,Zs), labeling([],Zs).
Xs = [22,22], Zs = [11,11,11,11,22,22] ;
false.

?- sumFD([12,81],[11,44],Xs,Zs), labeling([],Zs).
Xs = [24,25], Zs = [12,81,11,44,24,25] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

`digit` is a recursive predicate. I don't see recursion in your definition.

The base case is of course when the digit is 0, and the list is empty:

```
digit(0, []).
```

The recursive case however is split in two, depending wether first argument is the variable, or the second:

```
digit(X, [Y|Ys]) :- nonvar(Y), digit(Z, Ys), X is Y + 100 * Z.
digit(D, [X|Xs]) :- nonvar(D), D>0, X is mod(D,100), R is div(D,100), digit(R, Xs).
```

Now you can use `digit` either way:

```
?- digit(12345,X).
X = [45, 23, 1] ;
false.

?- digit(X,[45,23,1]).
X = 12345.
```

note that the list is reversed! You can make it output already reversed (I'll leave it as an excercise for you, while I'll use `reverse/2` here; hint: use [accumulators](http://people.sju.edu/~jhodgson/ai/accums.html)).

```
sum(A,B,R) :- reverse(A,AR), reverse(B,BR),
              digit(A1,AR), digit(B1,BR),
              R1 is A1+B1,
              digit(R1,RR),
              reverse(R,RR).

?- sum([11,11],[11,11],X).
X = [22, 22] .

?- sum([12,81],[11,44],X).
X = [24, 25] .
```

Comment: Why not use [tag:clpfd]?

Comment: I intend to not use the digit function as recursive function,it is just for making sure that the summation of two heads of the list is just of single or two integers and the extra digit S should be added to next integer.Yeah I've missed that the list should be reversed because I should begin summing from the right to the left,thanks allot.

Comment: @repeat and I'd like to read the solution using [clpfd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clpfd), so why don't you add one?